# Functional Development On The CLR

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming, clr

If this has already been asked and answered, please point me to the existing Q & A and I'll delete this question.  I did look and didn't see this one answered.

Are there mainly functional languages (like LISP, Scheme, Haskell and so forth) besides F# for the CLR platform?  I say "mainly functional" because realize there are CLR languages that have functional constructs like (Iron)Python but I wouldn't consider Python as a functional language.

I'm asking because I'm doing a presentation on FP and concurrency for some other developers at work and they're asking me about F# (we use a Microsoft tool stack) and I want to make sure they're aware of all possible options.

---

EDIT

From the answers below:

[IronScheme](http://www.codeplex.com/IronScheme)

[hsdotNet](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/hs-dotnet)

[Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org) (for .Net)

[Nemerle](http://nemerle.org/Main_Page)

And I've seen stuff about a CLR version of [Clojure](http://www.clojure.org).  Thanks everyone for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [IronScheme](http://www.codeplex.com/IronScheme).

Comment: Thanks--this is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

A Scala port is available too, but it doesn't seem to be really up to date.

Some links with further informations:

[Getting startet with Scala on .NET](http://hestia.typepad.com/flatlander/2009/01/getting-started-with-scala-on-net.html)

[Is Scala .NET production ready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743172/is-scala-net-production-ready)

[Scala on Microsoft .NET](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/168)

Another Language worth a try is obviously [Nemerle](http://nemerle.org/Main_Page) which looks as it may be the most usable of the suggestions in this Thread!

Comment: Thanks.  I knew about the Scala stuff but Nemerle is new to me.

Answer (score 1):

[hs-dotnet](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/hs-dotnet) allows you to write Haskell code that interfaces directly (and in-process) with CLR code, but the Haskell code doesn't actually run on the CLR.

Comment: Thanks.  Not exactly what I wanted but still worth a look.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does this compare to http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Salsa ?

Comment: Salsa aims for type safety but is much less complete.